# How to copy and paste rows of other tabs in workbooks back to a master workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Afternoon,

I am attempting to copy over multiple ROWS from multiple (3) tabs in multiple workbooks.

So far I have written code that will grab the first tab of multiple workbooks and copy and past every row into one "master" workbook.

I am good with that.

However, I am lacking the ability to be able to copy the rows in the other tabs within the workbooks!

This is really bugging me and hopefully someone out there can help me.  I went ahead and dropped my code in below so you can get a better idea of where I am.

GOOD NEWS:  All workbooks contain 3 tabs.  They are formatted in the same manner.  I just need to figure out how to copy and past the rows of the other tabs in these workbooks back to the master workbook.

Thanks in advance.

```
    'Description: Combines all files in a folder to a master file.
     Sub MergeFiles()
     Dim path As String, ThisWB As String, lngFilecounter As Long
     Dim wbDest As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
     Dim Filename As String, Wkb As Workbook
     Dim CopyRng As Range, Dest As Range
     Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer

     RowofCopySheet = 2 ' Row to start on in the sheets you are copying from

     ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

     path = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
     MsgBox "Get Ready!"

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     'Deletes all rows
     Sheets("RAW").Select
     Rows("2:2").Select
     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
     Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Sheets("BK").Select
Rows("2:2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Sheets("RAW").Select
'End delete all rows

'Pick folder
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    'End pick folder

     Application.EnableEvents = False


    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
     Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
     If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
     Do Until Filename = vbNullString
     If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
     Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
CopyRng.Copy Dest


Wkb.Close False
End If

Filename = Dir()
Loop

'Remove Duplicates
Range("A1").Select

Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$40002").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
Range("F20").Select

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'End Remove Duplicates

MsgBox "Voila!"
End Sub
```

I think I may have solved this!

```
    'Description: Combines all files in a folder to a master file.
Sub MergeFiles()
Dim path As String, ThisWB As String, lngFilecounter As Long
Dim wbDest As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim Filename As String, Wkb As Workbook
Dim CopyRng As Range, Dest As Range
Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer

RowofCopySheet = 2 ' Row to start on in the sheets you are copying from

ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

path = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
MsgBox "Get Ready!"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Deletes all rows
Sheets("RAW").Select
Rows("2:2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Sheets("BK").Select
Rows("2:2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Sheets("RAW").Select
'End delete all rows

'Pick folder
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    path = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
'End pick folder

Application.EnableEvents = False

'Sheet 1
Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until Filename = vbNullString
If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
CopyRng.Copy Dest

Wkb.Close False
End If

Filename = Dir()
Loop

'Sheet 2
Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until Filename = vbNullString
If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
Application.GoTo Wkb.Sheets(2).Range("A1")
Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(2).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
CopyRng.Copy Dest

Wkb.Close False
End If

Filename = Dir()
Loop

'Sheet 3
Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until Filename = vbNullString
If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
Application.GoTo Wkb.Sheets(3).Range("A1")
Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(3).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
CopyRng.Copy Dest

Wkb.Close False
End If

Filename = Dir()
Loop


'Remove Duplicates
Range("A1").Select

Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$40002").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
Range("F20").Select

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'End Remove Duplicates

MsgBox "Voila!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Option Explicit

PUblic Function FileBrowse(Optional FilenameToSearchFor As String, Optional Caption As String = "")
  On Error GoTo error_Handler
    Dim lngCount As Long
Dim xFilename As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim xFileNPath As String
Dim tmp As Variant

' Open the file dialog
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    If Caption <> "" Then
      .Title = Caption
    End If
    .InitialFileName = FilenameToSearchFor
    .Show

    ' Display paths of each file selected
  For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
    xFilename = .SelectedItems(lngCount)
    FileBrowse = xFilename
   ' If IsWorkbookOpen(xFilename) Then
   '   Workbooks(xFilename).Close SaveChanges:=False
   '  'Exit Sub
   ' End If
   ' Workbooks.Open xFilename
  Next lngCount
End With

   Exit Function

 error_Handler:
   Debug.Print "FileBrowse", Err, Err.Description
   Stop


 End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your Folder/File picker in a separate function that you can call to return the selected folder or files.

If you want it to open all saved files in a folder then you have to use the DIR() command to get the list of files (and their paths). Google Excel VBA Dir for sample code.

Set up separate variables for the Target and Source workbooks and worksheets to use in a loop:
    Dim sWS as worksheet
    dim tWS as worksheet
    dim sWB as workbook
    dim tWB as workbook
    dim sRange as range
    dim lRow as long

```
'use dir command to locate the first source workbook

lrow = tws.usedrange.rows.count + 1
'open the first workbook

set swb = workbooks.open(filename)
for each sws in swb.sheets
  set srange = sws.usedrange
    'copy from source to next available cell
  srange.copy tws.Range("A" & lRow)
  lrow = tws.usedrange.rows.count + 1
next sws
```

This will copy each tab from each workbook to the next available row in tws.

Comment: First of all - THANK YOU for helping!

I will be honest though- this is a little confusing as I thought I already had the Folder/file picker function in place with my existing code.

Also - I don't really see where you are going with the rest of the code.  Still new at VBA.

Comment: the file picker should be in it's own function so you can call it, have it return a file to open then process that file, by looping through it's worksheets. You have the option of calling a folder and processing all the files within the folder or simply processing them one file at a time.

Comment: The code shows how to loop through an open workbook and copy one worksheet at time to the target worksheet.

Comment: So, I used what you were tying to get to and basically - simplified it.  Thanks again for the help.  Teamwork can really MAKE THE DREAM WORK :)